# Problems reading files with letters and numbers

Tags: python, list, file, readfile

I'm trying to work with a file that contains a header a set of numbers separated by double space and some text at the end (as shown in the image below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bziZ.png)

My goal is to extract these numbers so that I can build a graph with them. Another problem is that the program's decimal separator is a comma and python uses a period.

I feel like this is pretty easy to do, but my stupidity limits me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot provide you a precise answer since we don't have access to the exact file. I'm using this as example.

[image: I'm using this as sample.txt]
[Check Pastebin here.](https://pastebin.com/r6aMBsBr)

So the code goes:

```py
f = open("sample.txt","r")
file_lines = f.read().splitlines()
header_lines = file_lines[1]
# split takes a separator as first argument
headers = [k for k in header_lines.split("  ")]
numbers_line = file_lines[2]
# strip remove spaces from the start and end "                1  2 3"
numbers_line = numbers_line.strip().split("  ")
# in my example data starts at 4th line and ends at 8th line (inclusive)
data_line_start = 4
data_line_end = 8
data_lines = file_lines[data_line_start-1:data_line_end]
# format data_lines remove spaces from start and end
data_lines = [j.strip() for j in data_lines]
# data_lines => DATA LINES
# ['0.03592  0.04902  0.0248  0.0327  0.0520  0.0318', '0.0553  0.06602  0.0548  0.0232  0.0710  0.0782', '0.08413  0.04402  0.0348  0.0654  0.0612  0.0428', '0.0543  0.06202  0.0148  0.0732  0.0810  0.0882', '0.0443  0.04102  0.0343  0.0556  0.0652  0.0928']
# we still need to format this using doble space as separator
data_array = []
for data_line in data_lines:
    data_line_formatted = [float(k) for k in data_line.split("  ")]
    data_array.append(data_line_formatted)
print("HEADERS")
print(headers)
print("NUMBERS LINE")
print(numbers_line)
print("DATA ARRAY")
print(data_array)
```

OUTPUT:

```
HEADERS
['Plate:', 'PLate1', '1.3', 'PlateFormat', 'EndPoint', 'Absorbance', 'Reduced', 'FALSE', '1', '1', '410', '1', '12', '96', '1', '5']
NUMBERS LINE
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
DATA ARRAY
[[0.03592, 0.04902, 0.0248, 0.0327, 0.052, 0.0318], [0.0553, 0.06602, 0.0548, 0.0232, 0.071, 0.0782], [0.08413, 0.04402, 0.0348, 0.0654, 0.0612, 0.0428], [0.0543, 0.06202, 0.0148, 0.0732, 0.081, 0.0882], [0.0443, 0.04102, 0.0343, 0.0556, 0.0652, 0.0928]]
```

You can use the [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function to open a file, then get a list of line files and storing into file_lines variable, what's next is just using some python [string methods](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp) to format the data.
The script below might not be useful but you can adapt it to your needs. Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me a lot! People like you make the internet good.

Comment: This error is popping up: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\x00'

Comment: Upload your file to pastebin so i can take a look at the format. You may need to open it in byte mode. But i need to have the precise file format.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for bother. Here is the link: https://pastebin.com/9zBVETQ9

Comment: As i told you, your file use tabulator ("\t") as separator. So the final code is here https://pastebin.com/WaxbWLJk .Hope this works for you!. I'd suggest to mark the answer as closed.

Comment: Thaks again! And sorry for not closing it, i didn't know how to do it.